# Ability to update list without reloading it when editing a row using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this code:
     http://jsfiddle.net/nickbuus/82q8j/11/

When I press edit on the "row" and then update I am updating the data on the server and then reloading all of the rows using:

```
 GetFoods('catname');
```

I am using knockoutjs - is there a clever way to connect and  update the particular row in the list that was edited without having to reload all of the rows on update?

Comment: An alternative to the answer below is to consider breeze.js.  Very easy to use and handles retrieving, caching, updating, deleting, etc... With only one controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ApiController, you should add three new methods

- Create a new item
- Update existing item
- Get info of a specific item

With these methods you will be able to do what you are looking for.
I also suggest you to have a look at [knockout.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) and more specifically at the ko.mapping.fromJS and toJS functions.